# UnsupportedCharsetException: IS646-US with JDK 1.8u51 on Solaris 5.10

Tags: java, jdbc, solaris

I tried to start a java enterprise application (running on JBoss 4.3) on Solaris 5.10 using JDK 1.8u51. Unfortunately I get the following exception from the jdbc driver:

```
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: IS646-US
```

Does anyone know what's up with that? It all works without problems on JDK 1.7u65

Here's the stacktrace:

```
java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: IS646-US
    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:531)
    at sun.nio.fs.Util.<clinit>(Util.java:41)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystem.<init>(UnixFileSystem.java:52)
    at sun.nio.fs.SolarisFileSystem.<init>(SolarisFileSystem.java:43)
    at sun.nio.fs.SolarisFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(SolarisFileSystemProvider.java:46)
    at sun.nio.fs.SolarisFileSystemProvider.newFileSystem(SolarisFileSystemProvider.java:39)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.<init>(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:56)
    at sun.nio.fs.SolarisFileSystemProvider.<init>(SolarisFileSystemProvider.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.createProvider(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:48)
    at sun.nio.fs.DefaultFileSystemProvider.create(DefaultFileSystemProvider.java:61)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.getDefaultProvider(FileSystems.java:108)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.access$000(FileSystems.java:89)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder$1.run(FileSystems.java:98)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder$1.run(FileSystems.java:96)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.defaultFileSystem(FileSystems.java:96)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems$DefaultFileSystemHolder.<clinit>(FileSystems.java:90)
    at java.nio.file.FileSystems.getDefault(FileSystems.java:176)
    at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2234)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(SeedGenerator.java:190)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$1.run(SeedGenerator.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.getSystemEntropy(SeedGenerator.java:168)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(SecureRandom.java:201)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:221)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:468)
    at oracle.security.o5logon.O5Logon.a(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.security.o5logon.O5Logon.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.<init>(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:566)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:370)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:207)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:139)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource.java:88)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:1598)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.makeOneConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:515)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getCacheConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:475)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleImplicitConnectionCache.getConnection(OracleImplicitConnectionCache.java:357)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:395)
    at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getConnection(OracleDataSource.java:179)
...
```

Comment: Are you sure this is IS and not ISO?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `ISO646-US` (or better known as ASCII or US-ASCII)

Comment: Yes, I only copy/pasted everything. It's IS.

Comment: It looks like you are running with a `-Dfile.encoding=IS646-US`, either explicitly in the startup configuration of the application or implicitly by an incorrectly configured OS(?).

Comment: It was sun.jnu.encoding from the jboss start which had IS646-US set, it had a typo which didn't seem to have had any effect with Java 7. Thanks a lot for the help! Do you want to post that as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a typo, it should be ISO646-US (better known as ASCII or US-ASCII).

Likely cause is that you are running with a `-Dfile.encoding=IS646-US` (or similar), for example explicitly in the startup configuration of the application server.